# Chord Theory Basics

Tags: chords

I really do not understand piano chord theory and how to do inversions (are first and second the only ones?),and the numbers on chords (i.e. Cm13; C Sharp 7 etc.) how can I make myself understand this better?  Are there better books on this?

All the books presume knowledge but I want something very basic or a basic web site or video somewhere.

Comment: Questions seeking external resources are off-topic here, but there are already lots of questions and answers about chords and inversions on the site. Try looking at questions under the [tag:chords] tag for starters: there are 1089 questions there at the moment.

Comment: See also [tag:chord-theory]!

Answer (score 2):

There are as many inversions as there notes in the chord.  A triad (3 notes) has three inversions - called root position, first inversion and second inversion - any of the three notes may be at the bottom.   A seventh chord (4 notes) has four inversions.    We don't normally go beyond this point - a C9 chord voiced as D, E, G, Bb, C COULD be called 'C9, fourth inversion' but generally isn't!

On piano, distinguish between 'voicings' and 'inversions'.   Voicing is about texture, how notes are spaced. Inversion is about harmony, which note is the lowest.  There's no point in talking about the 'inversion' of a RH chord on piano when there's a LH note as well.  That's the one that defines the inversion.

Comment: I see your point about a triad having three inversions, but we normally call them root position, first inversion, and second inversion, no? Saying "three inversions" may be a bit confusing; a beginner may conflate "root position" with "first inversion" and get in a whole mess of trouble.

Comment: Nice, clean, to the point.

Comment: An inversion is a change from an original. So with three notes to play with, so to speak, there's an original (root) and only *two* inversions. Yes, it's slightly pedantic, but what you state may confuse someone at the stage  the OP is, at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Using a triad as a start point. Three notes which make up a standard chord. It's 1,3 and 5. Let's take G major. That's G B D. With the G (chord note name) at the bottom, it's called *root position*. Put the B as the bottom note, it's now *1st inversion*. Now put D underneath, it's *2nd inversion.*

With either of the other two notes either way round, those names still stand. It could be a *closed* chord, with the 3 notes as close as possible to each other, or a *open* chord, where there's a missing note, which could be played but isn't, in between a couple of notes that are played.

That's simple chords. Major and minor. The numbers game is next. Generally, after 1,3,5, comes 7. The 7th note in the scale is added to the original triad. C maj 7 adds the maj.7th note. Cm7 adds the minor 7th note. When we see C7, it's short for C dominant 7, and uses the maj. triad, but adds a m7.

That's it for now, as you can probably guess what 9, 11, 13 might entail. Suffice to say that numbers larger than 7 will often also contain the 7th note  as well. There's more later, maybe.